# We do not instantiate ImageView and still it works

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is `ImageView` an abstract class as we write:

```
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class LoadActivity extends Activity {
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    ImageView im;
    Animation rotate;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.load_icon);
        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.load_page);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        im.startAnimation(rotate);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        P1.class);
                startActivityForResult(nextPageIntent, 0);
            }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        im.startAnimation(rotate);

    }
}
```

So we do not use `new` keyboard to instantiate it. I'm not able to understand please help. This is my whole code.

My problem is that `ImageView` is not an abstract class but `ImageView im;` is working.
Should not it be `ImageView im = new ImageView()`;

Why this is not used?

Comment: Take a look into the documentation% http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: Your code won't work - please post the actual code you're using....and as has been said, `ImageView` is not an abstract class and `findViewById` is used to find 'views' that have been 'inflated'.

Comment: @PallaviChoudhary similar question, does `Object obj;` make class `Object` final?

Comment: i did not understand what u mean Sufian

Comment: @PallaviChoudhary : OK, now you've added more complete code, what do you suppose `setContentView(R.layout.load)` does? Basically that processes your `load.xml` file and implicitly inflates all of the 'views' in that file. In other words it does the work of calling `new` on each and every view for you. When you then call `findViewById(R.id.load_icon)` it's basically asking the `Activity` to find the `ImageView` which was created as part of the inflation process.

Comment: @Sufian : What do either of you comments have to do with inflating Android views?

Comment: @Squonk:setContentView works as it is defined under Activity and my class is extending activity but not ImageView?I understand that it is ultimately creating view but compile checks everyline how will it understand that an object of ImageView is created

Comment: @Squonk I was emphasizing on the point that `ImageView im;` doesn't tell anything about the class itself being abstract or anything, as the OP used it to raise the question.

Comment: @PallaviChoudhary Your class doesn't need to extend `ImageView`. I'll say again...your layout xml file (load.xml) *CONTAINS* an `ImageView` definition. Calling `setContentView(R.layout.load)` *INFLATES* that xml file and creates all of the views in that file. Calling `findViewById(...)` simply gets a reference to any view that has been used as part of the inflation process and used as part of the 'content view' - in other words, what will be seen on the screen.

Comment: @Squonk :Thanx i understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageView is not an abstract class.

`findViewById(int)` is to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

Or *It Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).*

`ImageView` is extended from `View` class so we will get a View instance from its ID using this method

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not an abstract class and can be instantiated with many constructors.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is not ans abstract class.

`findViewById(int)` is to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you have programmatically and handles it by itself.

Views are inflated by layoutInflator. When you call setContentView xml layout is parced and view hierarchy is created.

attributes passed to Button's constructor by layout inflater. check [LayoutInflator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,android.view.ViewGroup,boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

No. Have a look at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java)

It's typically written out like that because you typically inflate a view and all of the child views in the hierarchy will be constructed for you.